# Database design: same table - mixed data VS several tables - same schema

Tags: mysql, database, schema

I would like to store information about people (who have a `person_id`) that is quite similar to each other, such as:

- profession
- nationality
- tags
- etc. = limited amount of characteristics which is not expected to grow in number

Since one person can have more than one tags (or professions for example), it makes sense to normalise the database. All these information require a simple table design: `primary key` (`id`) + `varchar`.

I am wondering what makes more sense:

1. Store mixed information in one table = one schema
2. Store information in distinct tables, but tables have the same schema

**Edit**

This information and the people are connected in a third table: `primary key` | `person_id` | `property_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1]One should store information in distinct tables having same schema, if your database is OLTP (Online transaction processing).Later you can use various joins to retrieve table data.

2]You should keep mixed information in one table if your database is for data mart/data warehouse/ data mining purpose where performance is not an issue but information related MIS is having more wheitage.